# Quicksort and insertsort on an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
$db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
//-select  the database to use
$mydb=mysql_select_db("address");

$aArray = array();
$sSQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM address1",
mysql_real_escape_string($ir['fname'])
);
$rResult = mysql_query($sSQL);
while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rResult))
{
$aArray[] = $aRow;
}
//print_r($aArray);
 echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";


$unsorted = $aArray;

function quicksort($array)
{
    if (count($array) == 0)
        return array();

    $pivot = $array[0];
    $left = $right = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i] < $pivot)
            $left[] = $array[$i];
        else
            $right[] = $array[$i];
    }

    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot), quicksort($right));
}

$sorted = quicksort($unsorted);

print_r($sorted);
?>
```

I'm trying to pull some data from a MySQL database (2500 rows of data) then store that data into an array then do a quick-sort on that array. I don't know if my approach is wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated. So far I keep getting an error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\koolbi\heapsearch.php on line 25

Comment: Why do you not just sort the data during your SQL query?

Comment: Indeed, you should prefer to sort your data in SQL, it will be easier and faster.

Comment: And why write all the logic for a quicksort when PHP has that built-in?

Comment: @MarkBaker its the lectures orders. Its for a course called analysis of algorithms so the built in function wont cover the requirements., But how do i access the built in function?

Comment: Any of the built-in array sort functions use quicksort as its core algorithm... you say that the built-in function won't handle the requirements, not even array_multisort() or usort()? You don't seem to be doing anything particularly clever that the built-in sorts couldn't handle

Comment: @NickMitchinson can you give me an example of how i would do this via the sql statement. im kinda new to php where sorts are concern i only know how to pull and push data to a database

Comment: SELECT * FROM address1 ORDER BY [field you want to order by] http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp

Answer (score 1):

I will summarize the comments into an answer for future reference. The best solution here would be to order the results in your MySQL query; in this case `SELECT * FROM address1 ORDER BY [your field] ASC|DESC`; where ASC|DESC will select the order. For more information on MySQL ordering, check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp), or the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

As well, as Mark Baker stated, if you need to do it in PHP, use the built in functions. Most languages bulit-in functions will be extremely efficient at what they do (in fact I believe most of PHP's are written natively in C), making them MUCH faster than anything you could write yourself.

Of course if this is a school assignment where you need to implement a Quicksort algorithm you should probably check out [this community maintained explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).